# how to the get the Pentaho table values with Decimal

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-cde

I am using Pentaho-code I am round the queries values as decimal but getting some colums values not decimal

table output:

```
NORMAL (06:00--17:00)    3  14341.54    43024.62            
OFF_PEAK (22:00--06:00)  3  7002.39     21007.170000000002          
PEAK (17:00--22:00)      3   9362.95    28088.850000000002
```

required output

```
NORMAL (06:00--17:00)    3  14341.54    43024.62            
OFF_PEAK (22:00--06:00)  3  7002.39     21007.17            
PEAK (17:00--22:00)      3   9362.95    28088.85
```

Comment: Can you please confirm the issue belongs to pentaho-spoon or pentaho-CDE? if its is belong to pentaho -cde (table) then you can look Column formats property and set column with format like ‘%.2f’

Comment: adding with Column formats ‘%.2f’ just getting two values like  43,21,28

Answer (score 0):

Column formats %.2f will definitely work to show 2 decimal point. You just need to be define column formats for every column. For string you need to define %s, for only real digit use %d, and to get 2 decimal you need to define %.2f etc.

You can have a look in my sample image for correct configuration-

[image]